# must specify an iv error using attr_encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-kms, attr-encrypted

I'm trying to add an encrypted jsonb field to my user model in rails. I'm getting an error when attempting to read or set a value.

#### error

```
irb(main):002:0> User.last.q2_email_address = "bob@bob.com"
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Encrypt Data Key (190.1ms)  Context: {:model_name=>"User", :model_id=>11}
/Users/antarr/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/encryptor-3.0.0/lib/encryptor.rb:61:in `crypt': must specify an iv (ArgumentError)
```

#### user.rb

```rb
    has_kms_key eager_encrypt: :fetch_id
    attr_encrypted :settings, key: :kms_key, mashall: true
  
    store :settings,
          accessors: [:address1, :address2, :city, :customer_id, :customer_name, :customer_primary_cif, :social_security_number,
                      :email_address, :first_name, :group_desc, :group_id, :home_phone, :aba, :hq_session_id, :language, :last_name,
                      :login_name, :middle_name, :mobile_phone, :postal_code, :ssn, :state, :user_logon_id, :user_id, :user_primary_cif,
                      :work_phone, :ip_address, :token], coder: JSON, prefix: :q2
```

#### migration

```
  def up
    add_column :users, :encrypted_kms_key, :text
    add_column :users, :encrypted_settings, :jsonb, null: false, default: '{}'
    add_column :users, :encrypted_settings_iv, :string
    add_index :users, :encrypted_settings, using: :gin
  end
```

#### config/initializer/aws.rb

```rb
Aws.config[:credentials] = Aws::Credentials.new(
  ENV['AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY'],
  ENV['AMAZON_SECRET_KEY']
)
```

#### Gemfile

```rb
gem 'attr_encrypted' # 3.1.0
gem 'aws-sdk-kms'
gem 'kms_encrypted'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there're 2 method `encrypt` in the gem `attr_encrypted`, one is class method and one is instance method, the instance method will automatically generate `random iv`, meanwhile the class method will not, it uses the `iv` you setup.

when you call `User.last.q2_email_address = "bob@bob.com"`, [this method](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/blob/master/lib/attr_encrypted.rb#L167) will call the class method `encrypt`, the instance method will not be called, so that if you don't setup `iv`, the error `must specify an iv (ArgumentError)` will be raised.

there's 2 ways to fix, the first one is setup the `iv`

```
attr_encrypted :settings, key: :kms_key, mashall: true, iv: SecureRandom.random_bytes(12)
```

unfortunately, another error will be raised (relate to `iv_len`) and i'm still not figure out the root cause and fix it.

the second way: copy [this method](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/blob/master/lib/attr_encrypted.rb#L166-L169) into the model so that the instance method `encrypt` will be called, a random `iv` will be generated, and it works.

however, in case of `store attributes`, it does not save `encrypted attribute`, for example

```rb
user = User.last
user.settings = {....}
user.save! # OK

user.q2_email_address = "bob@bob.com" 
user.settings # changed, but not re-encrypt `encrypted_settings`
user.save! # changed settings will not be saved
```

so i came up with an idea that we can create a module support `store attributes` as below

```rb
# model/concern/store_encrypted.rb
module StoreEncrypted
  def self.extended(base)
    base.class_eval do
     # initialize store attributes values with default `{}`
     # so that a new object or existed object that miss iv
     # will generate random iv
     def initialize(*args)
      super(*args)
      @@store_attr_encryptes.each do |attribute|
        instance_variable_get("@#{attribute}") || send("#{attribute}=", {})
      end
     end

      alias old_save! save!
      def save!(**options, &block)
        # re-set attribute (encrypt again)
        @@store_attr_encryptes&.each do |attribute|
          send("#{attribute}=", send("#{attribute}"))
        end
        old_save!(**options, &block)
      end
    end
  end

  def store_encrypted(attribute, options={})
    @@store_attr_encryptes ||= []
    @@store_attr_encryptes << attribute
    attr_encrypted attribute, key: options[:key], marshal: options[:marshal]
    store attribute, accessors: options[:accessors], coder: options[:coder], 
                      prefix: options[:prefix], suffix: options[:suffix]
    # copy
    define_method("#{attribute}=") do |value|
      send("encrypted_#{attribute}=", encrypt(attribute, value))
      instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", value)
    end
  end
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend StoreEncrypted
  has_kms_key eager_encrypt: :fetch_id
  store_encrypted :settings, key: :kms_key, mashall: true,
                  accessors: [...], coder: JSON, prefix: :q2
end

#
user = User.last
user.q2_email_address = "bob@bob.com" 
user.save! # it'll re-encrypt settings
```

Comment: I tried your last approach with the Concern. I'm still getting the same error. ```irb(main):003:0> u.mature_driver_discount = 3.0
/Users/antarr/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/encryptor-3.0.0/lib/encryptor.rb:61:in `crypt': must specify an iv (ArgumentError)```

Comment: You can see my current changes here https://gist.github.com/antarr/91a4a92bd88241af1e6b593ea8a808c0

Comment: @AntarrByrd, i think i missed initialize store attributes values, i updated my answer.

Comment: @AntarrByrd and you should create a db task to update `update!(profile: {})` for all legacy user records which existed before you add migration `encrypted_profile`.